# Retrieving values after submitting fetcher

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this handler submitting a fetcher

```
const fetcher = useFetcher();

const handlerLogin = () => {
  fetcher.submit({ value: 'social', value1:'second', value3:'third' }, { method: 'POST' });
};
```

It is accessing the action method properly (router 6). I could access all the values in the first array (parameter) as:

```
export async function action({request, params}){
    const formData=Object.fromEntries(await request.formData())
    console.log(formData.value1) ---> prints: second
```

How could I access the value(s) passed in the second array, i.e. `{ method: 'POST' }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of the method property by using dot notation or bracket notation, like this:

```
console.log(request.method);  // print "POST"
```